# Jhipster Entity Generation Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I am using JHipster and I am at the point where the entities has to be set. I'm facing off an issue that doesn't allow me to generate an entity.

Basically I created a .jdl file and then I imported that on my JHipster project. The problem is that I am not able to generate all the entities. More in the specific the entity "Quiz".

Which could be the problem?

This is the log:

```
Error: ERROR! Copying template src/test/java/package/web/rest/_EntityResourceIntTest.java failed. [TypeError: /Users/manu/app/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/entity-server/templates/src/test/java/package/web/rest/_EntityResourceIntTest.java:199
    197|     private static final Integer <%=defaultValueName %> = <%= defaultValue %>;
    198|     private static final Integer <%=updatedValueName %> = <%= updatedValue %>;
 >> 199| <%_ } else if (fieldType === 'Long') { _%>
    200| 
    201|     private static final Long <%=defaultValueName %> = <%= defaultValue %>L;
    202|     private static final Long <%=updatedValueName %> = <%= updatedValue %>L;

Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined]
    at Environment.error (/Users/manu/app/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:157:40)
    at module.exports.error (/Users/manu/app/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:2030:18)
    at ejs.renderFile (/Users/manu/app/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/utils.js:193:23)
    at tryHandleCache (/Users/manu/app/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:226:12)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/Users/manu/app/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:437:10)
    at Object.renderContent (/Users/manu/app/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/utils.js:189:9)
    at module.exports.template (/Users/manu/app/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-private.js:528:23)
    at blockTemplate.templates.forEach (/Users/manu/app/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:2348:42)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports.writeFilesToDisk (/Users/manu/app/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:2325:45)
```

This is the .jdl file's part where Quiz is used.

```
entity Position {
    positionId Integer,
    description String,
    domain String,
    status String,
    createdBy String,
    createdOn LocalDate,

    quizId Integer
}

entity Quiz {
    quizId Integer,
    quizName String,
    startDate LocalDate,
    endDate LocalDate,
    status String,
    marks String
    questionsNumber Integer,
    questions String[],
    complexity String
}

entity Question {
    questionId Integer,
    section String,
    description String,
    optionA String,
    optionB String,
    optionC String,
    optionD String,
    answer String,
    marks String,
    status String,
    complexity String,

    quizId Integer
}

entity Result {
    resultId Integer,
    obtainedMarks String,
    percentage Double,
    appearedOn String,

    quizId Integer,
    customUserId Integer
}

relationship OneToMany {
    Position{quizId} to Quiz{quizId}
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Quiz{quizId} to Result{quizId}
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    Question{quizId} to Quiz{quizId}
}
```

All the entities goes well except "Quiz", I don't know why.
Could someone please spend some time to help me?
I would be happy for this, I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entity generator most probably fails upon reaching the part where you declare relationships. The field you put in `{}` is supposed to be of the relationship *target type* and not an `Integer`.

For example, if the following piece of code:

```
relationship OneToMany {
    Position{quiz} to Quiz
}
```

means that you want JHipster to create a field named `quiz` in `Position` which **will be of the type `Quiz`**. Also, you're not supposed to declare the fields both in the `relationship` and the `entity` sections. Above all, you don't need any `id` fields as these are added by JHipster to all entities by default.

Simply remove all the `quizId` fields from your entity declarations. JHipster will create the fields corresponding to relationships between entities, using the information provided in the `relationship` blocks. You might want to rename the fields used in `relationship` blocks, since they will end up being the actual referenced objects (and not their ids).

Comment: Thank you so much. I found your post very helpful. Have a nice day!